# Solving Time-constrained CVRP with two vehicle types in Google or-tools

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I am modeling a Time-constrained CVRP. The problem is to minimize the total travel time (not including the package dropping time) subject to vehicle (delivery) capacity and total time spent (per vehicle) constraints. The package dropping time refers to an additional time to be spent at each node, and the total time spent equals to the travel time plus this additional time. I have the below model that works for a single vehicle-type case. I would like to introduce two-vehicle type concept in there, meaning that I have a set of `V1` type vehicles and another set of `V2` type vehicles. The only difference of the vehicle-types is the per time cost of travel. Let `x` denote the per time unit cost of travel by `V1`, and `y` denote the per time unit travel cost of `V2`. How can I design the model so that it incorporates this additional aspect?

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def create_data_model(n_vehicles):
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = TT #travel time
    data['num_vehicles'] = n_vehicles
    data['depot'] = 0
    data['demands'] = demands
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = vehicle_capacities
    data['service_time'] = service_time
    return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    max_route_time = 0; tour = {i:[] for i in range(data['num_vehicles'])}
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_time = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            tour[vehicle_id].append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            if previous_index != 0 and previous_index <= len(data['service_time'])-1:
                service_time = data['service_time'][previous_index]
            else:
                service_time = 0
            route_time += (routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id) + service_time)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        tour[vehicle_id].append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Travel time of the route: {} sec\n'.format(route_time)
        print(plan_output)
        max_route_time = max(route_time, max_route_time)
    print('Maximum of the route time: {} sec'.format(max_route_time))
    return(tour)

def main(n_vehicles):
    number_of_veh = [n_vehicles][0]
    solution_found = False
    while solution_found == False:
        """Entry point of the program."""
        # Instantiate the data problem.
        data = create_data_model(number_of_veh)

        # Create the routing index manager.
        manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                               data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
        # Create Routing Model.
        routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

        # Create and register a transit callback.
        def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
            """Returns the time between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

        transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

        # Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

        # Create and register a transit callback.
        def time_callback2(from_index, to_index):
            """Returns the time between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            if from_node != 0:
                return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node] + data['service_time'][from_node]
            else:
                return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

        transit_callback_index2 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback2)

        # Add Time constraint.
        dimension_name = 'Time'
        routing.AddDimension(
            transit_callback_index2,
            0,  # no slack
            Operational_hours*3600,  # vehicle maximum travel time
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            dimension_name)
        time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)

        def demand_callback(from_index):
            """Returns the demand of the node."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            return data['demands'][from_node]

        demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
            demand_callback)
        routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
            demand_callback_index,
            0,  # null capacity slack
            data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            'Capacity')

        # Setting first solution heuristic.
        search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
        search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
            routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
        search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
            routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
        search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(VRP_time_limit)

        # Solve the problem.
        solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

        # Print solution on console.
        if solution:
            tour = print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
            solution_found = True
        else:
            print('No solution found! Increasing the vehicle numbers by one and resolving.\n')
            solution_found = False
            number_of_veh += 1
    
    return(tour, number_of_veh)
```

**EDIT**

Based on @Mizux' answer, I have written the following, which produced the below error.

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def create_data_model(n_vehicles):
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    TT = np.array(df.values)
    data['time_matrix'] = TT
    data['num_vehicles'] = n_vehicles
    data['depot'] = 0
    data['demands'] = demands
    if len(vehicle_capacities) < n_vehicles:
        data['vehicle_capacities'] = [vehicle_capacities[0]]*n_vehicles
    else:
        data['vehicle_capacities'] = vehicle_capacities
    data['service_time'] = service_time
    return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    max_route_time = 0; tour = {i:[] for i in range(data['num_vehicles'])}
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_time = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            tour[vehicle_id].append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            if previous_index != 0 and previous_index <= len(data['service_time'])-1:
                service_time = data['service_time'][previous_index]
            else:
                service_time = 0
            route_time += (routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id) + service_time)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        tour[vehicle_id].append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Travel time of the route: {} sec\n'.format(route_time)
        print(plan_output)
        max_route_time = max(route_time, max_route_time)
    print('Maximum of the route time: {} sec'.format(max_route_time))
    return(tour)

def main(n_vehicles, cost1, cost2):
    number_of_veh = [n_vehicles][0]
    solution_found = False
    while solution_found == False:
        Num_of_Class6 = int(n_vehicles*Percent_of_Class6)
        Num_of_Hybrid = n_vehicles - Num_of_Class6
        V = list(range(n_vehicles))
        V2 = list(set(np.random.choice(V, size=Num_of_Class6, replace=False)))
        V1 = list(set(V)-set(V2))
        """Entry point of the program."""
        # Instantiate the data problem.
        data = create_data_model(number_of_veh)

        # Create the routing index manager.
        manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                               data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
        # Create Routing Model.
        routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
        '''Major Diff Starts Here'''
        # Create and register a transit callback.
        def time_callback(from_index, to_index, cost):
            """Returns the time between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]*cost

        range_extender_callback = partial(time_callback, cost=cost1)
        class6_callback = partial(time_callback, cost=cost2)

        transit_callback_index_V1 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(range_extender_callback)
        transit_callback_index_V2 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(class6_callback)
        '''Major Diff Ends Here'''
        # Define cost of each arc.
        for v in V1:
            routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(transit_callback_index_V1, v)
        for v in V2:
            routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(transit_callback_index_V2, v)

        # Create and register a transit callback.
        def time_callback2(from_index, to_index):
            """Returns the time between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            if from_node != 0:
                return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node] + data['service_time'][from_node]
            else:
                return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

        transit_callback_index2 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback2)

        # Add Time constraint.
        dimension_name = 'Time'
        routing.AddDimension(
            transit_callback_index2,
            0,  # no slack
            Operational_hours*3600,  # vehicle maximum travel time
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            dimension_name)
        time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)

        def demand_callback(from_index):
            """Returns the demand of the node."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            return data['demands'][from_node]

        demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
            demand_callback)
        routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
            demand_callback_index,
            0,  # null capacity slack
            data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            'Capacity')

        # Setting first solution heuristic.
        search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
        search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
            routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
        search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
            routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
        search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(VRP_time_limit)

        # Solve the problem.
        solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

        # Print solution on console.
        if solution:
            tour = print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
            solution_found = True
        else:
            print('No solution found! Increasing the vehicle numbers by one and resolving.\n')
            solution_found = False
            number_of_veh += 1

    return(tour, number_of_veh, V1, V2)

main(n_vehicles, cost1, cost2)
```

The output is:

```
Beginning the Googe OR-tools to solve the problem.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0447402a4e3d> in <module>
    166     return(tour, number_of_veh, V1, V2)
    167 
--> 168 final_tour,number_of_veh, V1, V2 = main(n_vehicles, cost1, cost2)

<ipython-input-15-0447402a4e3d> in main(n_vehicles, cost1, cost2)
    104             routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(transit_callback_index_V1, v)
    105         for v in V2:
--> 106             routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(transit_callback_index_V2, v)
    107 
    108         # Create and register a transit callback.

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py in SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(self, evaluator_index, vehicle)
   5224     def SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(self, evaluator_index: "int", vehicle: "int") -> "void":
   5225         r""" Sets the cost function for a given vehicle route."""
-> 5226         return _pywrapcp.RoutingModel_SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(self, evaluator_index, vehicle)
   5227 
   5228     def SetFixedCostOfAllVehicles(self, cost: "int64_t") -> "void":

TypeError: in method 'RoutingModel_SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle', argument 3 of type 'int'
```

Comment: Please verify your `v` in the for loop V1,V2 is an int

Comment: Interestingly, when I wrap `v` in the for loops with `int()`, it works! I thought `range()` produces integer values, and indeed tested (`[type(i) for i in V1]` returns `[int, int]`) and saw that they are integers. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply register two transits callbacks (i.e. one per vehicle type)

Then use the overload of AddDimension() to pass an array of registered transit callback index.

e.G. [Mizux/vrp_multiple_transit.py](https://gist.github.com/Mizux/6d9283388150020df7542adf63577786)

Comment: Just to ensure I am getting it correctly, can you please also answer: The travel time/speed is independent from vehicle type in my case. The only difference is the cost of travel time for each vehicle type. Would only setting something like this in addition to the posted code be satisfactory? If yes, after which line should it go (e.g., routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles)?
`for v in V1:
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(x, v);
for v in V2:
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(y, v)`

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. I should replace `routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)` with what I proposed above. But, before that, I should reorganize `time_callback(from_index, to_index)` such that it returns `data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]*x` and `*y`. So, one way is creating two callbacks as you suggested. A nod would be appreciated though!

Comment: I gave a try to it following your modeling convention but got an error. I updated my answer with the change in the code including the error. You may search '''Major Diff Starts Here''' to see where the change is. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, I followed Mizux' answer. I have the below MWE for future consideration. I hope it helps to someone!

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

n_vehicles = 4 #Number of vehicles
max_vehicle_tt = 3600 #Maximum travel time for each vehicle (excludes service times)

data = {}
data['time_matrix'] = np.array([[   0, 1187, 1200, 1110, 1134,  892, 1526,  903, 1482, 1544],
                             [1232,    0,   13,   90,   67,  426,  537,  419,  493,  555],
                             [1218,   57,    0,   82,   73,  412,  523,  405,  479,  541],
                             [1177,   90,   90,    0,   23,  370,  481,  364,  438,  500],
                             [1187,   80,   67,   23,    0,  380,  491,  374,  448,  509],
                             [ 870,  390,  403,  314,  337,    0,  729,   17,  686,  747],
                             [1539,  557,  543,  485,  495,  733,    0,  726,   53,   68],
                             [ 882,  384,  397,  307,  331,   17,  723,    0,  679,  741],
                             [1496,  514,  500,  442,  451,  689,   53,  683,    0,  122],
                             [1584,  602,  588,  530,  539,  777,   68,  771,  122,    0]])
data['num_vehicles'] = n_vehicles
data['depot'] = 0
data['demands'] = [0, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 12, 1, 24, 20]
data['vehicle_capacities'] = [30]*data['num_vehicles']
data['service_time'] = [0, 18, 18, 27, 25, 11, 92, 6, 239, 143]

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    max_route_time = 0; tour = {i:[] for i in range(data['num_vehicles'])}
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_time = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            tour[vehicle_id].append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            if previous_index != 0 and previous_index <= len(data['service_time'])-1:
                service_time = data['service_time'][previous_index]
            else:
                service_time = 0
            route_time += (routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id) + service_time)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        tour[vehicle_id].append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Travel time of the route: {} sec\n'.format(route_time)
        print(plan_output)
        max_route_time = max(route_time, max_route_time)
    print('Maximum of the route time: {} sec'.format(max_route_time))
    return(tour)

def main(n_vehicles, cost1, cost2):
    np.random.seed(0)
    Num_of_Class6 = int(n_vehicles*0.6)
    Num_of_Hybrid = n_vehicles - Num_of_Class6
    V = list(range(n_vehicles))
    V2 = list(set(np.random.choice(V, size=Num_of_Class6, replace=False)))
    V1 = list(set(V)-set(V2))
    print('V1:%s'%V1); print('V2:%s'%V2)
    
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    
    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index, cost):
        """Returns the time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]*cost

    range_extender_callback = partial(time_callback, cost=cost1)
    class6_callback = partial(time_callback, cost=cost2)

    transit_callback_index_V1 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(range_extender_callback)
    transit_callback_index_V2 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(class6_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    for v in V1:
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(transit_callback_index_V1, int(v))
    for v in V2:
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(transit_callback_index_V2, int(v))

    # Create and register a transit callback to limit the total travel+service time
    def time_callback2(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        if from_node != 0:
            return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node] + data['service_time'][from_node]
        else:
            return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index2 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback2)

    # Add Time constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Time'
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        transit_callback_index2,
        0,  # no slack
        [max_vehicle_tt]*data['num_vehicles'],  # vehicle maximum travel time
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)

    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(1)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        tour = print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
        return(tour, V1, V2)
    else:
        print('No solution found!\n')


tour,V1,V2 = main(n_vehicles,0.5,0.7)
```

**Bonus**: Use the below function to check critical solution metrics.

```
pairs = {}; serv_time = {}; tt ={}; cont_to_obj = {}
for i,j in tour.items():
    if len(j) > 2:
        serv_time[i] = sum([data['service_time'][k] for k in j])
        print('Service time for vehicle %s: %s.'%(i,serv_time[i]))
        num_deliveries = sum([data['demands'][k] for k in j])
        print('Number of deliveries for vehicle %s: %s.'%(i,num_deliveries))
        pairs[i] = list(zip(j,j[1:]))
        tt[i] = sum([data['time_matrix'][k] for k in pairs[i]])
        print('Travel time for vehicle %s: %s.'%(i,tt))
        print('Total time for vehicle %s: %s'%(i,serv_time[i]+tt[i]))
        if i in V1:
            cont_to_obj[i] = sum([int(data['time_matrix'][k]*0.002244) for k in pairs[i]])
        else:
            cont_to_obj[i] = sum([int(data['time_matrix'][k]*0.0080517) for k in pairs[i]])
        print('Contribution to the obj. fun. for vehicle %s: %s\n'%(i,cont_to_obj[i]))
```